# Visual Studio 2008 Question, table adapters connections string issue

Tags: visual-studio, connection-string, datasource

I have a data source that I use for creating reports in my programme. I've recently changed the connection string to the table adapters created by the wizard(ConString1), because I wanted to make that connection string available to every other class that needs  to use it. So basically. I deleted the application setting created by the wizard(ConString1) and entered in my own application setting(ConString). Once debugging began all the code that still refered to the now non existent connection string(ConString1), I changed to the available one(ConString). That is in the code the debugger picked up. The program works fine.

Now my problem is this, when I select a table adapter and take a look at its properties, the Connection string is still set to the old connection string name, the connection string value itself is given as "Unable to find connection ". This is prohibiting me from adding new tables to my reports.xsd file.

I also keep getting an error when trying to create a new datasource.

Error : Could not load type Microsoft.VisualStudio.DataDesign.SyncDesigner.SyncFacade.SyncManager.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right-click on the data-set xsd, select "Open With..."
2. Select "XML (Text) Editor" and click OK.
3. Modify as needed, and **be careful**.
4. **Be careful**.